# Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_both()

Tags: mysqli

I'm trying to create a dummy login page as a practice. I keep getting this error:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_both()

Code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['LOGIN'])){

    $EMAIL = $_POST['loginusernameinput'];
    $PASS = $_POST['loginpasswordinput'];

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM userinformationtbl WHERE Email ='$EMAIL' AND password ='$PASS'");

    $row = $result -> fetch_both(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["userID"] = $row["userID"];
    header ('location: account.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to read how to give proper titles to your question.

Comment: Code format, exception format, grammar and title

Answer (score 0):

Unless you defined it in your code, `fetch_both` is not a PHP function.
That's why you get:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_both()

`PDO::FETCH_BOTH` is a constant in the [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php), which means it can only be used with a PDO connection and PDO functions.

`MYSQLI_BOTH`is a [MySQLi constant](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php).

Fix your code:

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Documentation: [mysqli_result::fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)